# GETTING ERROR-- ORA-00936:MISSING EXPRESSION for below query please help on this

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT CASE (SELECT Count(1)
               FROM   wf_item_activity_statuses_v t
              WHERE  t.activity_label IN ('WAITING_DISB_REQ',
                                          'LOG_DDE',
                                          'LOG_SENDBACK_DDE')
               AND    t.item_key IN(
                           SELECT r.i_item_key
                           FROM   wf_t_item_xref r
                           WHERE  r.sz_appl_uniqueid = '20400000988')
            )
              WHEN 0 THEN
                     (
                            delete
                            from   t_col_val_document_uploaded p
                            WHERE  p.sz_application_no = '20400000988'
                            AND    p.sz_collateral_id = 'PROP000000000PRO1701'
                            AND    p.i_item_key = '648197'
                            AND    p.i_document_srno = '27' )
              WHEN 1 THEN
                     (
                            DELETE
                            FROM   t_col_val_document_uploaded p
                            WHERE  p.sz_application_no = '20400000988'
                            AND    p.sz_collateral_id = 'PROP000000000PRO1701'
                            AND    p.i_document_srno = '28' )
              ELSE NULL
       END
FROM   dual;
```

Comment: You can't nest a `DELETE` inside a `SELECT` like that.  You're trying to 'abuse' `CASE` expressions to provide the procedural logic of `IF`.  I recommend starting [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/if_statement.htm) for understanding Oracle's `IF` statements and PL/SQL

Comment: What is `count(1)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate your query and make sure to follow the flow of the clauses properly, please check the next two links to get a better understanding :

[[ORA-00936: missing expression tips]](https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-00936-missing-expression/)

How do I address this **ORA-00936** error?

Answer:  The Oracle oerr utility notes this about the **ORA-00936** error:

**ORA-00936** missing expression
Cause: A required part of a clause or expression has been omitted. For example, a **SELECT** statement may have been entered without a list of columns or expressions or with an incomplete expression. This message is also issued in cases where a reserved word is misused, as in **SELECT TABLE**.

Action: Check the statement syntax and specify the missing component.

The **ORA-00936** happens most frequently:

1 - When you forget list of the column names in your **SELECT** statement.
2. When you omit the **FROM** clause of the SQL statement.

[ora-00936-missing-expression](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00936_missing_expression.htm)

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a simple select query like this. You have to use a PL/SQL block like below -

```
DECLARE NUM_CNT NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
     SELECT Count(1)
       INTO NUM_CNT
       FROM wf_item_activity_statuses_v t
      WHERE t.activity_label IN ('WAITING_DISB_REQ',
                                 'LOG_DDE',
                                 'LOG_SENDBACK_DDE')
        AND t.item_key IN(SELECT r.i_item_key
                            FROM wf_t_item_xref r
                           WHERE r.sz_appl_uniqueid = '20400000988');
     IF NUM_CNT = 0 THEN
        delete
          from t_col_val_document_uploaded p
         WHERE p.sz_application_no = '20400000988'
           AND p.sz_collateral_id = 'PROP000000000PRO1701'
           AND p.i_item_key = '648197'
           AND p.i_document_srno = '27';
     ELSIF NUM_CNT = 1 THEN
           DELETE
             FROM t_col_val_document_uploaded p
            WHERE p.sz_application_no = '20400000988'
              AND p.sz_collateral_id = 'PROP000000000PRO1701'
              AND p.i_document_srno = '28' )
     END IF;
END;
```